# How to format the queryset in Django Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I want to display the month and totalpayment in tabler or readable form from the queryset value.

Models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
  statementperiod = models.DateField(default = date.today())
  paymentdate = models.DateField(default = date.today())
  paymentamount = models.IntegerField()
  paymentmethod = models.CharField(max_length=100 )
  Status = models.CharField(max_length = 250, default = 'paid', choices = PAYMENT_CHOICES)
  Paynote = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null = True, blank = True)

  @classmethod
  def totalpayment(cls):
        total = Payment.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('paymentdate')).values('month').annotate(total_payment=Sum('paymentamount'))
        return { total}
```

QuerySet value in the template:

```
{<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2019, 11, 1), 'total_payment': 315}, {'month': datetime.date(2019, 12, 1), 'total_payment': 8348}, {'month': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'total_payment': 6292}]>}
```

How to format these values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "intcomma" template tag from humanize django application to format the total_payment:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize/

From the docs:

> To activate these filters, add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Once you’ve done that, use {% load humanize %} in a template, and you’ll have access to the following filters.

Template example:

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ total_payment|intcomma }}
```

And, depending on how you want to format the month, humanize has the "naturalday" and "naturaltime" template tags.
But, you can also use the "date" filter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Example:

```
{{ month|date:"M" }}
```

Comment: It is not making any change in the queryset value when I use the intcomma.

Comment: I updated the answer. Did you add the humanize app in INSTALLED_APPS? Also, you need to load it in the template. If it doesn't work, show a snippet of code from your template where you use it.

Comment: I have added in INSTALLED_APPS. But, I am returning the variable "total" to the template. When I return "total_payment" variable, I am getting the error "total_payment" not defined. Can you fix this error?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show me your template code, and/or your view?

Comment: template code"{% load humanize %}
  {{total_payment|intcomma}}                                                                   
  models.py  @classmethod
      def totalpayment(cls):
            
            total = Payment.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('paymentdate')).values('month').annotate(total_payment=Sum('paymentamount'))
            return { total_payment}